# MVC 4 Razor JQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

The client side validation doesn't work when validation rules are added dynamically from external JavaScript file. The same rules works well when added from webpage.

In partial's model I have simple validation attributes:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[Display(Name = "Serial Number")]
public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
```

Coresponding partial view includes AJAX form with input field and error message:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegisterSerialNumber", "SerialNumber", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "serialNumberLens", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { id = "serialNumberForm" }))
{ 
    <div class="input-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SerialNumber, new { @class = "form-control input-sm inline-element", placeholder = "Serial Number" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SerialNumber)
```

Client side validation code is a sample from web and it's shows a Bootstrap popover:

```
$('#serialNumberForm').validate({
        rules: {
            serialNumber: {
                minlength : 3,
                required  : true
            }
        },
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            $.each(this.successList, function (index, value) {
                return $(value).popover('hide');
            });

            return $.each(errorList, function (index, value) {
                var _popover;
                _popover = $(value.element).popover({
                    trigger   : 'manual',
                    placement : 'top',
                    content   : value.message,
                    template  : '<div class=\"popover\"><div class=\"arrow\"></div><div class=\"popover-inner\"><div class=\"popover-content\"><p></p></div></div></div>'
                });
                _popover.data("bs.popover").options.content = value.message;

                return $(value.element).popover('show');
            });
        }
    });
```

When I added this JS code to a partial, it's works as expected and popover displayed in case of empty text field and when number of entered characters are less than 3. But when I moved this rules to external JS file (inside jQuery document loaded event block - `$(function () {})`), or even pasted it to browser dev consle, it doesn't work.

I think, the root cause for this problem can be in internal MVC 4 client side validation, thats code is initialized before mine. Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to solve the issue. Could someone to put me to the right way?

Comment: what scripts you are rendering in the view/layout ?

Comment: a few pointers, make sure you have referenced the external JS file. Also make sure the file is referenced in the correct order. Is you code being called when you debug?

Comment: @KevDevMan - the code executed correctly - all breakpoints reached. I have to say that all JS files are added to one bundle and loaded simultaneously.

Comment: @Mayank - did you meant which libraries are used on this view? There are jQuery, jQuery Validation, jQuery Validation Unobtrusive, Bootstrap and some internal scripts.

Comment: have you added Jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js? You can turn the buncling off by adding BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false; to your bundleConfig

Comment: @KevDevMan Yes, this library is included.